# How do I solve the recurrence relation $f(n) = f(n - 1) + 3n + 2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to figure out how to find the closed form of a specific recurrence relation:

\begin{align*}
f(n) = f(n - 1) + 3n + 2
\end{align*}
where $f(0) = 2$ and $n\geq 1$.

My class notes only shows how to do it with summations but not with this form.

Nothing explains how to turn this formula into a summation either.

How may I find the closed form?

Comment: There a lots of ways, including treating this as a summation.  What have you tried?

Comment: Observe: $$f(1)=f(0)+5=7,$$ $$f(2)=f(1)+8=15,$$ $$f(3)=f(2)+11=26,$$ $$...$$

Comment: Observe that a linear term is being added each time, hence $f(n)$ must be a quadratic.

Comment: Have you tried just plugging in the formula and calculating the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Henry mentioned in his comment above, this is simply a summation

$f(k) = f(k-1) + 3 k + 2 $

So

$ f(k) - f(k-1) = 3 k + 2 $

Adding both sides from $k = 1$ to $n$

$ f(n) - f(0) = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^n 3 k + 2 $

Which simpifies to

$ f(n) - 2 = \dfrac{3}{2} n (n+1) + 2 n = \dfrac{n ( 3 n + 7 )}{2} $

Hence

$ f(n) = 2 + \dfrac{n ( 3 n + 7 )}{2} = \frac{1}{2}( 3n^2 + 7 n + 4)$

We can check several values

$f(0) = 2 $

$f(1) = 7 $

$f(2) = 15 $

etc.